# Convert C# to unmanaged C++

Tags: c#, c++

I have the unenviable task of converting a couple of C# (CCW) COM servers (one is an Activex Control) to unmanaged C++. Any suggestions on tools I could use to make this as easy as possible would be gratefully accepted.

Comment: I second @Danny Tuppeny's query. If the C# code already has a COM interface then it is perfectly usable in C++. Why bother converting?

Comment: I'd do that manually. ATL is called for, start by generating the interface/coclass headers with MIDL (from idl, perhaps extract that from the existing TLB (embedded in COM dll/ocx)), and just manually mirror the classes. Along the way, there will be many opportunities for scripting and copy/paste

Comment: Hi, the prime reason is the user doesn't want the hassle of managing the .Net runtime as part of the deployment. If you can suggest a way around that then great! ATL, etc... was the way I was gonna go, just wondering if there was anything that would make my life easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tangible Software sells a C# to C++ converter, but I've never used it myself...

http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/CSharp_to_CPlusPlus_Converter_Details.html

Comment: Thanks I'll give the demo a try

Comment: Great, just what I wanted. Still plenty of work to do, but definitely a time saver.